# pandas dataframe generate rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a Input dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

# Define the input data
data = {
    'ID':  [500, 200, 300],
    'A': [3, 3, ''],
    'B': [3, 1, ''],
    'C': [2, '' ,''],
    'D': ['', 2, 1],
    'E': ['', '',2 ],
}

# Convert the input data to a Pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Input table

[image]

I need to transform this input as you can see in below output example:

[image]

If you have any ideas please share. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) the rows using the [`max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) number per row, then compare to a [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to map the `1`/`''`:

```
tmp = df.set_index('ID').apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

out = (
 tmp.loc[tmp.index.repeat(tmp.max(axis=1))]
    .pipe(lambda d: d.gt(d.groupby(level='ID').cumcount(), axis=0))
    .replace({True: 1, False: ''})
    .reset_index()
)
```

*NB. you can simplify the code if you use `NaN` in place of empty strings.*

Output:

```
    ID  A  B  C  D  E
0  500  1  1  1      
1  500  1  1  1      
2  500  1  1         
3  200  1  1     1   
4  200  1        1   
5  200  1            
6  300           1  1
7  300              1
```